# Reshape matrix for correct minus operation of matrices with different dimension

Tags: matlab, reshape

I want to minus a matrix of `A=[60x60]` with a matrix of `B=[1x2]`. How do I shape the second matrix so that the minus operation is correct?

The minus operation can be defined as:
`A(k1,k2)-[a*k1 b*k2]`
Where `[a*k1 b*k2]=B`. To make it clearer, `A` is a matrix of phase of an image, however it was shifted by phase `B` in every `k1` and `k2` direction, thus `newA` will be the new phase of the image, described in equation below:

[image]

Where `/theta''` is the new phase of `A`. `a'` and `b'` is the matrix `B`

I tried like this:

```
A=rand(60);
B=rand(1,2);
newA=A(:)-B;
```

But I'm not sure it's correct. Will it shift all the matrix in `A` by `B`? or is it just shift the first row of `A`? what about the value of `k1` and `k2` in `B`? Appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the subtraction operation you're trying to perform. You want to subtract `B` from all the values of `A`? Or subtract `B` from only two values of `A`?

Comment: Hi, I want to subtract `B` from all the values of `A`

Comment: Simply turn `B` into a `240x320` matrix using `repmat(B,[240,160])`, then subtract it from `A`.

Comment: It might be better if you give an example of 4*4 matrix. It kinda get confusing

Comment: Your notation is confusing. How does `a` and `b` both become the matrix `B`?  Please provide a **small numerical example** to accompany your question.

Comment: @smttsp @rayryeng Sorry for confusing, I edited the question to 60x60 matrix. However I still not sure If I perform the operation correctly(based on the equation). I think something is not right on matrix `B`, it would be something `a*k1+b*k1`, but after did that, it will be a one dimension matrix. Please ask me if anything not clear, I'll rephrase again.

Comment: As I said before and I'll say again. Please provide a small numerical example. Not doing this will most likely result in your question being closed.

Comment: It would be nice if you give an example of a `4*4 matrix`. Assume `A` is 1:16. Please give values to `a', b', k1, k2`, and give the output matrix, then we can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understood, you will subtract k1 from odd columns and k2 from even ones.

```
A2 = zeros(size(A));
A2(:, 1:2:end) = A(:,1:2:end)-k1; 
A2(:, 2:2:end) = A(:,2:2:end)-k2;
```

Comment: Much better solution than using `repmat` as suggested above.

Comment: @rayryeng, why it is much better? I think they are kinda equal suggestions. I dont claim this technique is amazing but at least this is another technique OP should learn/know

Comment: I'm not sure if I explained myself clearly, but I tried my best. I edited the question, adding the formula to make it simple to understand. I still can't figure it out! Thank you guys!

Comment: @smttsp Using `repmat` requires creating a temporary replicated matrix.  You are not doing that and doing the subtraction in-place.

Comment: @rayryeng: Thanks for feedback but I kinda got confused. I create `A2 matrix` and do subtraction from `A` to `k1 `and `k2` whereas in `repmat` solution, Aziz subtracted the temporary matrix and set it to `A_new` which is almost the same operation as I did. Even he created a temporary matrix but I didn't. (On this dimensions, it wont change anything)

Comment: You could do it in place by mutating `A` but this apparently isn't what the OP wants. Waiting to see wait they want before providing more feedback.